# Permission Denied (publickey) ssh into rebuilt droplet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Rebuilt a droplet in digitalocean and now I can't login into my instance!

my `/etc/hosts` file has my ip address under howlit

Here is my output from: `ssh -vv root@howlit`

```
debug1: Host 'howlit' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/known_hosts:40
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fe5a8500950),
debug2: key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Changed anything with my IP address to 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX'

I tried setting my private key to be the one to identify with:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa howlit`

but that also came back as `Permission Denied(public key)`

Comment: in the end was not able to resolve except to recreate a new droplet. without the proper key and i didn't set up a root password I was not able to go in the droplet and change my keys.